# floor function equality ⌊x⌋^2=16

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

​

> $$⌊x⌋^2=16 $$
> $$⌊x⌋^2≤x^2≤⌊x⌋^2+1 $$
> $$16≤x^2≤17 $$
> $$-17<x<17 $$ not sure about the last step,is it correct? if so is it full answer? ty.

Comment: Your final answer does not make sense...take $x=16$, for instance.

Comment: The first step is already wrong. $⌊x⌋^2=16$ holds iff $⌊x⌋ = 4$ or $⌊x⌋ = -4$.

Comment: How about first you try to find $\lfloor x\rfloor$? Then figure out what $x$ may be.

Comment: Nor is it generally true that $\lfloor x\rfloor^2≤x^2$.  Take, say, $x=-.5$

Comment: guys can someone explain why my post got one down vote?

Comment: Why do you think $16 \le x^2 < 17$ would mean that $-17 < x < 17$?  Is it because you think $x <x^2 < 17$?  You don't want to widen the range or you get extraneous none solutions.  If we assume $16 \le x^2$ (which was not a correct conclusion-- $[x]^2\ne [x^2]$) then we *can't* have $0\le x^2 < 16$ and we *can't* have $-4 < x < 4$. so having the *wide* $-17< x < 17$ includes too many invalid values.

Answer (score 4):

We have:

$\lfloor x\rfloor^{2} = 16$

$\lfloor x \rfloor  = \pm 4$

Because the floor function outputs the greatest integer below or at the argument:

$\boxed{-4\leq x<-3\text{ or }4\leq x < 5}$

Comment: thanks,what you just explained is it considered full proof?

Answer (score 1):

None of the steps are correct.

$[x]^2 \ne [x^2]$.  Consider $x = 4.99$ then $[x]^2 = 4^2 = 16$ but $[x^2]=[4.99^2] = [24.9001] = 24$.

$16 \le x^2 < 17$ means $-17 \le x < 17$ is .... I don't get it.

if $16\le x^2 < 17$ were valid (which it isn't) the proper way to solve is $4 \le \sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt {17}$ so $4 \le |x| < \sqrt{17}$ and $-\sqrt{17} < x \le -4$ or $4 \le x < \sqrt{17}$.  But $16 \le x^2 < 17$ is not correct.

Proper step is to simply solve $[x]$: If $[x]^2 = 16$ then $[x] =\pm 4$ and then simply continue as in Joshua Wang's answer:  If $[x]=-4$ then $-4\le x < -3$ and if $[x]=4$ then $4\le x < 5$.